# Make for multiple similar rules

Tags: makefile

I have the following rules in my makefile:

```
pieces = King Queen Knight Rook Bishop Pawn

Chess: ChessMain.o ChessBoard.o
g++ -Wall -g ChessMain.o ChessBoard.o -o Chess

ChessMain: ChessBoard.hpp ChessMain.cpp
g++ -Wall -g -c ChessMain.cpp -o ChessMain.o

ChessBoard: ChessBoard.hpp ChessBoard.cpp
g++ -Wall -g -c ChessBoard.cpp -o ChessBoard.o

Piece: Piece.cpp Piece.hpp
g++ -c Piece.cpp -o Piece.o

King: King.cpp King.hpp Piece
    g++ -c King.cpp -o King.o

Rook: Rook.cpp Rook.hpp Piece
    g++ -c Rook.cpp -o Rook.o

...
```

and similar for all the other chess pieces (subclasses of `Piece`). How do I shorten these specific piece rules to one general rule? I tried

```
$(pieces): $($@:=.cpp) $($@:=.hpp)
    g++ -c $($@:=.cpp) -o $($@:=.o)
```

but it doesn't work.

---

I edited the full file in.

Comment: It doesn't work -- what happens? I assume you correctly indent the g++ line ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The makefile you show is not right.  All rules should use the file name that they actually build as the target name.  So having a rule with a target name `Piece` which generates an output file of `Piece.o` is wrong.

Second, you don't need to have object files depend on other object files.  Object files only rely on their source and header files.

Third, certainly you can create rules like this (see the GNU make manual sections on implicit rules, such as pattern rules):

```
all: King.o Piece.o Rook.o

%.o : %.cpp %.h
        $(COMPILE.cpp) -o $@ $<
```

and you're done.  Obviously there's more to your makefile (presumably you link these object files into a program) but since you didn't show anything else that's all we can help with.

ETA: the (first) makefile you show above is not right.  For example, you have the `Chess` target listing `ChessMain.o` as a prerequisite, but you have no rule in your makefile that tells how to build that file (you say how to build `ChessMain` but that's obviously not the same thing.  Make will likely use its own built-in rules for this, which is OK except that there won't be any prerequisites so it won't rebuild files when headers change.

You can write your makefile like this:

```
CXX      = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g

pieces = King Queen Knight Rook Bishop Pawn

Chess: ChessMain.o ChessBoard.o $(addsuffix .o,$(pieces))
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

%.o : %.cpp %.hpp
        $(COMPILE.cpp) -o $@ $<
```

That's it, that's the whole makefile.  Get rid of everything else (based on your example above).

I should point out that this is probably not good enough.  For example, I'd be shocked if the prerequisites listed here are sufficient.  Surely it's not true that no `.cpp` file every includes any header file other than its own `.hpp`?  Surely the `ChessMain.cpp` file for example must `#include` the `King.hpp` file, etc.?  That relationship is not represented here, so rebuilds will not be reliable.

Comment: And if the OP really wants `make King` to make `King.o`, then he can add a direct rule `King: King.o` (no action needed), and a `.PHONY: King Knight Queen Bishop Pawn` rule since they are phony targets.  However, it seems unlikely to be necessary.

Comment: Some target names were provided by the instructor, so I just followed a similar format for `Piece`...